# Format toUTCString as toLocaleString

Tags: javascript

How can I convert a UTC string as seen below to something like July, 31 2020?

```
const date = '2020-07-31'
const utc = new Date(date).toUTCString();
```

So instead of Fri, 31 Jul 2020 00:00:00 GMT, I would like July, 31 2020/

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you looked at the `Intl` web api?

Comment: Since you are creating the date with no time, you simply need to split on the fourth space.  simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method relies on just the `Date` object and basic string methods.

```js
const date = '2020-07-31'
const utc = new Date(date).toUTCString();

function changeDate(str) {
  var months = {
    Jan: 'January',
    Feb: 'Febuary',
    Mar: 'March',
    Apr: 'April',
    May: 'May',
    Jun: 'June',
    Jul: 'July',
    Aug: 'August',
    Sep: 'September',
    Oct: 'October',
    Nov: 'November',
    Dec: 'December',
  }
  
  var str2 = new Date(str).toLocaleString()
  str2 = str2.split(/,/)[0].split(/\//g)
  str2 = months[str.split(/,/)[1].trim().split(/ /g)[1]] + ', ' + str.split(/,/)[1].trim().split(/ /)[0] + ' ' + str.split(/ /)[3]
  
  return str2
}

console.log(changeDate(utc))
```

Comment: I went with a variation of this approach. Thanks @GalaxyCat105

Answer (score 1):

[moment](https://momentjs.com/docs/) is good to use for handling date and time.

```
moment('2020-07-31').format('MMMM, DD yyyy')
```

[Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/docs) is good for an alternative `moment` since they recommend to use it ;).

`DateTime.local().toLocaleString(DateTime.DATE_FULL);`

Comment: I would also suggest to read the [Project Status of moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/) in the documentation.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure why everyone else is making it complicated.  Instead of using toUTCString, simply use `new Date(date).toDateString()`
This will give you the result you wish because toDateString doesn't have time in it.  Since you're creating it from a string without time in the first place, it doesn't make sense to treat it as a utc string anyway.

Answer (score -1):

```
  const formatSelectedDate = (date) => {
    const utcDayDateTime = new Date(date).toUTCString();
    const utcDateTime = utcDayDateTime.split(',')[1];
    const splitUtcDateTime = utcDateTime.split(' ');
    const month = splitUtcDateTime[2];
    const day = splitUtcDateTime[1];
    const year = splitUtcDateTime[3];
    return `${month}, ${day} ${year}`;
  };
```